# hyperlink onClick window.open

Tags: hyperlink, onclick

Hello I use a hypertext link looking like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.2n.cz/en/products/m2m/smartcom-pro/', '_blank')">basic information</a>
```

I have a problem when I use this script, the browser always open for me 2 new tabs. One is with the address i wrote, second is my web address. How to solve this issue I wanna stay on my page but wanna open a new tab with the address. Thank you very much with a help!
Using Chrome, Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="JavaScript: return !window.open('http://www.2n.cz/en/products/m2m/smartcom-pro/');">basic information</a>
```